# TortoiseSVN - push only a subset of modified files to branch while leaving the rest

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, commit, svn-trunk

Let's say I have a branch where I have modified a couple of files. Let's say these files are `file1` and `file2`.

Inside `file1` I have made modifications that affect only a feature that I'm currently implementing in my own branch. However inside `file2` I have made modifications that fixes a bug that affects other branches from other developers.

I was told that I can push only `file2` inside `branch` so that it will be made available to everyone else. The problem is I have no idea how to do that.

Do I have to commit **all** modifications in my branch and then somehow push only the committed changes to `file2` or can I make a "partial commit" (if such thing exists) for my `file2` and then push the changes from that commit to branch? I am using **TortoiseSVN 1.8.10** (not allowed to update it).

Comment: I suppose you're referring to the [Commit only parts of files](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html) feature but I have no idea about the version when it was added. In any case, working copies are cheap, you can create as many as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two solutions:

- Download `trunk` and replace the required files. Of course this should only be done if you are absolutely sure that the modifications don't break anything. Since I made a recent update of my branch (today actually) I'm sure that there are no problems with the modifications.
- Commit all changes except the ones you want to push to `trunk`, switch to `trunk`, commit the specific files there and then switch back to your own branch

Answer (score 1):

From my limited experience, whenever I try to commit using tortoise, you can see all the files that will be commited and uncheck the ones you don't want to commit.

Comment: True but it's not that simple. We are talking about two different branches here. I've found two solutions which I'll post.